# How long can a pure math(Algebraic Number theory) PhD holder can work as a Post Doc/research associate in their career?

Tags: mathematics, postdocs, career-path, research-assistantship

This is rather a curious question based on future career after PhD, looking at the crisis in academic/teaching job market.

If one completes PhD with pure mathematics (Algebraic Number Theory) with few good(not excellent) publications and to some extent good background (not excellent). Assume they are not ga enius but they are hard working. Assume they are searching for a permanent job in college/university teaching but is suffering while there are options to work as post-doc/research associates for them.

**The question:**

Exclude the possibility of getting a permanent teaching job. Can one prefer to work as a post-doctoral/research associate throughout ones whole (at least upto 40 years) career including several institutions and in any country ?

or, simply

How long can a researcher remain as a post-doctoral/research associate in several institutions and several countries, in algebraic number theory, in their career ?

Comment: If you are more than 6 years past your degree, I can’t hire you as a postdoc. But that is just one institution. Perhaps you should look to research labs or industry rather than academia.

Comment: I think that the differences between different countries or even institutions are really large in this context. Do you want to specify a locale?

Comment: @Christian, I didn't get you. But I meant I am ready to work any country not just my home country. For example, after working 1/2 years in some institution, I can go to any country for new appointment as post-doc/research associate. My question is-how long can one continue such process ? For example, the comment of Jon Custer says, he won't take anyone if one got PhD 6 years ago.

Comment: @JonCuster, thanks for your nice comment

Comment: @MAS I know of institutions which do not have such requirements but might not be able to give you a temporary contract more than once. Some countries like Germany have an overall time limit for temporary positions. So, I do not think that it is possible to give a reasonable answer which goes beyond "it depends".

Comment: @Christian, thanks for your comment

Comment: @DanRomik, I think astronomy and pure mathematics has a difference in the sense that one can work on astromy in many physics/engineering laboratory. In pure mathematics there is less possibility in that way

Comment: *but is suffering* --- Depending on what this means (financial suffering? current department/university politics suffering? current academic bullying suffering? current living location too hot, too cold, too dangerous, etc.?), being more specific might help with replies being more relevant to your personal situation.

Comment: @DanRomik, yes thanks

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, I think it is clear and obvious because i have used the term "job crisis in market"

Comment: @MAS I'm not sure that there is really a "crisis" in the academic job market; "crisis" implies something restricted to some moment in time. Rather, there are simply fewer long-term academic jobs than there are people trained with a PhD. This isn't particularly new, and is certainly not new since the time you started your PhD.

Comment: @MAS " For example, the comment of Jon Custer says, he won't take anyone if one got PhD 6 years ago" You are misinterpreting the "can't". The institution will not allow him to hire anyone 6 years past his PhD. Each instiutions will have different rules.

Comment: @MAS "one can work on astronomy in many physics/engineering laboratory" Absolutely not, there are way less astronomy position than pure mathematics, and physics/engineering laboratories are hiring (sometimes) physics and engineers. But they also have to spend a lot of money on machineries/tools/computers. Actually, *you* are more likely to work in those labs, rather than an astronom (keep in mind, you still have very low chances, but relatively higher than an astronom)

Comment: @BryanKrause, sorry, but I don't agree at all. How can someone who is established understand the difficulties faced by early career stragglers ?   In my country we say "unemployment crisis" when the vacancies comes out is very less with respect to number of applicants every time. Due to Pandemic, the situation has come to at more  severe situation. New recruitment advertisement  has been very less